# Accept value from a variable to SQLITE execute statement

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am using SQLITE as my database in Phonegap but the value of the variable is not being accepted in tx.execute statements

```
var name=document.getElementByID("Txtname").value;
 var age=document.getElementByID("Txtage").value;
   function populateDB(tx)
 {     
   tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');  
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)'); 
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, '"+name+"')');  
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, '"+age+"')');
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this simple string concatenation.

```
executeString = "INSERT INTO DEMO (id,data) VALUES (1,'"+name+"')";
tx.executeSql(executeString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jsfiddle or similar. ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zcsa963y/))

```
db = window.openDatabase('demo',1,'demo',1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE demo (`id` unique, `data`);");
   var query = "INSERT INTO `demo` (id,data) VALUES(?,?);";
   var values = [1,"abc"];
   tx.executeSql(query, values);
});
```

Or inline

```
db = window.openDatabase('demo',1,'demo',1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
   tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE demo (`id` unique, `data`);");
   var name = "abc";
   tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO demo (`id`,`data`) VALUES(2,'"+name+"');");
});
```

*Note if you try the first then second example, it will fail because your trying to CREATE the table again and then because the ID is not unique, this may have been your original issue.

You won't get any errors in the console. Best to see what's going on by providing the success/error handlers.

```
db = window.openDatabase('demo', 1, 'demo', 1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  var name = "abcd";
  tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO demo (`id`,`data`) VALUES(1,'" + name + "');", [], successHandler, errorHandler);
});

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
  alert("Error : " + error.message);
}

function successHandler(transaction, result) {
  alert("Success : " + result.rowsAffected + " rows affected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how things work in PhoneGap, but I think you need to encapsulate your queries in double-quotes `"`, not single-quotes `'`

```
tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO");
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)");
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, '" + name + "')");
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, '" + age + "')");
```

Comment: are you  sure your database/table is created at first place? uninstall your app and then try